# HTC Desire has trouble to establish connection via Wifi

Tags: wi-fi, connection-issues

I have a HTC Desire running Froyo (2.2). When I get home, the desire takes a long time before it establishes a connection with my Wifi broadband. Sometimes restarting the router works, other times switching to "Airplane" mode and then enabling Wifi and then disabling "Airplane" mode makes the connection. I have a [Netcom NB5+4w](http://www.netcomm.com.au/netcomm-products/adsl-broadband/nb5plus4w) modem. I know that current HTTP activity delays the switch to Wifi from 3G. But even when there is no http traffic running on my phone it spends all of it's time "obtaining IP address" from the router. I don't run many apps and I force close many of them in case they are blocking access. But it doesn't seem to make a difference

Has anyone else had similar problems ? and do you have a reason/solution ?

Comment: Sounds like bad modem firmware.  If you're fully updated, I recommend flashing an older modem that performs better  -- XDA would be a good place to look.

Comment: you might also try manually assigning an IP to your device - that might result in a faster connection. Also see, if you face similar connectivity issues with other WiFi access points / routers in auto mode.

Comment: I have done that. Still inconsistent connection handshake. I have removed foursquare which has improved things as well as tweetDeck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the absence of a definitive answer I did a lot of experimentation. Firstly, if you have http intensive apps this version Android (2.2), won't change connectivity until the operation is complete.

Switch to Airplane mode. You can still connect to your router but app traffic is suspended. You shield get a connection at this point. Deactivated Airplane mode and you should be running on your router. If anyone can nominate tools that can help track http app activity on android, Please post.

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed the same thing happening occasionally - I find that if I turn the wifi (on the phone) off and on again it will usually pick the wireless network up straight away - that's not quite as drastic as having to enable/disable airplane mode.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using HTC Desire with Froyo and have a Netcomm NB6Plus4Wn, but haven't exprienced any problems with connecting to Wifi.

Is your home Wifi one of the saved Wifi networks on your phone? (It should do this automatically if you've connected once before). I find that the phone takes much longer when searching for new networks, but is fairly quick if it is connecting to an existing/saved one.

Also, I've had some problems with 3G Internet and this was solved by turning the phone off and on - maybe give that a go?

Comment: Yes to all of the above, I have found that "on/off" of the phone works sometimes. Also found that the Netcomm routers are a bit glitchy with devices. I have assigned static IP addresses to all devices at home as well. After much experimentation the best solution has been to enable airplane mode and then connect.